# Luggage Storage in Nashville

Tags: luggage-storage, nashville, bna

I'm going to a concert in Nashville this weekend. The problem is, I have a luggage and I don't wanna carry it around. I will arrive at the airport in the afternoon and the concert will be until midnight, and my flight is in the early morning the next day. So, I need to leave my luggage and pick it up before sun rise. Is there any option for me?

Comment: If you're only going to be in Nashville for less than 24 hours, what luggage are you bringing?

Comment: What venue is hosting the concert? I would think most theaters and arenas have a coat check that would accept a small backpack.

Comment: I'm on a business trip in vegas and I'm going to the concert before I go back to san francisco. That's why I bring quite a big luggage.

Comment: Ship your suitcase home via UPS after your last meeting wherever it is your business takes you. Then fly without baggage to Nashville.

Comment: For what it's worth [Sleeping In Airports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/usa/nashville.htm) says that there aren't any storage lockers at BNA. I thought there used to be some, but I don't remember seeing them lately. It's a bit of a hack, but [there is a place that rents storage units near the airport](https://www.extraspace.com/Storage/Facilities/US/Tennessee/Nashville/501615/Facility.aspx#cid=glbc). Spehro's rental car solution is probably better, though.

Comment: @pnuts I proposed a short wiki and excerpt for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sad, but noting [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g55229-i154-k8438992-Need_suggestion_for_luggage_storage_downtown-Nashville_Tennessee.html) I see Thrifty (probably others too) have a rental car available this weekend for about $26 USD (if you pay in advance, but the car is right at the terminal- no shuttle). (price below is shown in Canadian dollars @ ~ 0.76)

[image]

Yes, I have paid more to store luggage.

There may be stupid taxes and fees on top of this so check carefully, and of course you are going to have to be eligible to rent a car and probably have your own valid insurance to get this low a price, also they may (or may not) be okay with leaving it in the parking space it is sitting in when you arrive (I would guess it's not a problem).

Comment: You will almost certainly NOT be able to leave it in the rental lot overnight. And if you do decide to drive it, please be sure not to drink and drive (hey, I'm not sure what type of 'concert' it is!)

Comment: This is perfect. I rented a car for $16 and drive to the concert. Thanks spehro for your answer.

Comment: Wow, $16 is really cheap- where did you find that deal?. Glad it worked out for you!

Comment: I got the deal from E-Z Rent-A-Car through www.carrentals.com. However, other car rentals such as budget and avis also offered similar price for that day.

Answer (score 1):

We used a new service called [Stow Station](https://www.stowstation.com/), you book online and drop off your bags in a neighborhood downtown. The guys had all kinds of good suggestions for things to do while we waited to check in as well. Our hosts suggested them to us and we couldn't have been happier.

Answer (score -1):

I was thinking about this and here is a solution for you assuming you want to check your bag. If you arrive in Nashville in the afternoon, let's say 4 pm, and your departure flight isn't until early next morning, let's say 6 am. Then you are within the 24 hour check-in window for your departure flight. Assuming that you do not need anything in your suitcase, I would check in for your next flight when you arrive in Nashville and check your bag. That way, the airline already has it and you don't have to worry about it the next morning. Bonus, you'll already have your boarding pass for your departure flight.

Comment: Have you tried this before? In my experience, U.S. airlines will not accept bags for domestic flights more than 4–6 hours before departure, or prior to the day of departure.